# How to control the position of the text in the selector in antd UI？

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using [antd's selector](https://ant.design/components/select/#header), I want to add a prompt to the left of the selection box to indicate what this selector is used to select. I tried to use the label tag in the select tag, but this will give an error. I also thought about using pseudo-elements, but that didn't work. Do you know how to do it. The effect I want is as follows. The left side of the selection box is the prompt word, and the right side is the selection result of the selector.

[image]

Comment: You using react yes?

Answer (score 0):

There is no build-in way, you need to compose it from other components.

[For example](https://6g7i3.codesandbox.io/): using `CheckBox`, `Dropdown`, `Menu` and layout components like `Row` and `Col`

```js
const data = ['Jack', 'Lucy', 'Momo', 'Alex'];

export default function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState('Jack');

  const menu = (
    <Menu onSelect={({ key }) => setSelected(key)}>
      {data.map(item => (
        <Menu.Item key={item} value={item}>
          {item}
        </Menu.Item>
      ))}
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <FlexBox>
        <h3>All Checkboxed</h3>
        <Select defaultValue="Jack">
          {data.map(uniqueValue => (
            <Select.Option value={uniqueValue} key={uniqueValue}>
              <Checkbox>{uniqueValue}</Checkbox>
            </Select.Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FlexBox>

      <FlexBox>
        <h3>Side By Side</h3>
        <Checkbox disabled>
          <Select defaultValue="Jack">
            {data.map(uniqueValue => (
              <Select.Option value={uniqueValue} key={uniqueValue}>
                {uniqueValue}
              </Select.Option>
            ))}
          </Select>
        </Checkbox>
      </FlexBox>

      <FlexBox>
        <Card size="small" style={{ width: 120 }}>
          <Row type="flex" gutter={10}>
            <Col>
              <Checkbox disabled />
            </Col>
            <Col>
              <Dropdown overlay={menu} trigger={['click']}>
                <Row type="flex" style={{ alignItems: 'center' }} gutter={10}>
                  <Col>{selected}</Col>
                  <Col>
                    <Icon type="down" />
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </Dropdown>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Card>
      </FlexBox>
    </FlexBox>
  );
}
```

[image: Selected]

[image: Edit Q-57024443-CheckBoxRenderInSelect]